# Adding multiple columns from a list table

Tags: r, data.table

I've got two data tables as below:

```
> have1
        Column1  Column2  Column3
1:          100      200      159
2:          169      506      101
3:          100      200      636
---
123571      456      559      249
123572      654      883      423

> have2
      variable    value
1:       Apple     0.25
2:       Orange    2.68
3:       Pear      0.11
---
10:      Grape     5.27
```

What I'm trying to do is to add the *variable* from `'have2'` as columns and *value* as constant to `'have1'`, so the `'want'` is:

```
> want
        Column1  Column2  Column3   Apple  Orange   Pear.... Grape
1:          100      200      159    0.25    2.68   0.11      5.27
2:          169      506      101    0.25    2.68   0.11      5.27
3:          100      200      636    0.25    2.68   0.11      5.27
---
123571      456      559      249    0.25    2.68   0.11      5.27
123572      654      883      423    0.25    2.68   0.11      5.27
```

I'm hoping to not use `dplyr` and stick with base R or `data.table`.
This merging will need to be applicable for different sets of `'have1' & 'have2'` and `'want'`, so trying to avoid manually listing all the variables in the `cbind` (i.e., `cbind(have1, Apple=0.25 etc...)`...)

Any help, suggestions would be appreciated, thank you!!

Comment: so you are widening the data in table two ? and what is common between the two tables to link for any lookups?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(data.table)

cbind(have1, transpose(have2, make.names = "variable"))
```

**Output**

```
   Column1 Column2 Column3 Apple Orange Pear
1:     100     200     159  0.25   2.68 0.11
2:     169     506     101  0.25   2.68 0.11
3:     100     200     636  0.25   2.68 0.11
```

**Data**

```
have1 <- structure(list(Column1 = c(100L, 169L, 100L), Column2 = c(200L, 
506L, 200L), Column3 = c(159L, 101L, 636L)), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L))
setDT(have1)

have2 <- structure(list(variable = c("Apple", "Orange", "Pear"), value = c(0.25, 
2.68, 0.11)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
setDT(have2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is:

```r
library(data.table)

have1[, have2$variable := as.list(have2$value)]

have1
#>    Column1 Column2 Column3 Apple Orange Pear
#> 1:     100     169     100  0.25   2.68 0.11
#> 2:     200     506     200  0.25   2.68 0.11
#> 3:     159     636     636  0.25   2.68 0.11
#> 4:     200     350     450  0.25   2.68 0.11

# data
have1 <- data.table(Column1 = c(100, 200, 159, 200),
                    Column2 = c(169,506, 636, 350),
                    Column3 = c(100, 200, 636, 450))

have2 <- data.table(variable = c("Apple", "Orange", "Pear"),
                    value = c(0.25, 2.68, 0.11))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>